# In a "shared" git repository, how do see what user made what change in a git status?

Tags: git, repository

Sometimes we have to use shared repositories (multiple users on one box all using the same working copy). However, I haven't found a way to see who has made what changes BEFORE you make a commit. For instance, Person A changes some files and Person B changes some files. When you do a git status, you see all of the files between the two with no indication on who actually modified which file. I don't think this has a solution as you would probably need some mechanism in git to keep track of things per user, but I thought I would check in case I missed something.

Comment: Don't use the same working copy for multiple users. HD Space is cheap anyways.

Comment: Note that I said we **had** to. It has nothing to do with HD space, but that we can only set up one environment with the attached hardware the software is interfacing with. We can't spend tens of thousands of dollars in equipment and licensing so each person can have their own local repository and the nightmare it would be to make it so there is some sort of "switch" where users could change who the hardware talks to while people are trying to test isn't very practical either. Working in a shared repo/working copy has its fallbacks, but its the best solution we have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No. Git only knows / is aware of the fact that the files in your working copy have changed; it has no knowledge of the working copy beyond that.

Also, that's probably a really bad development model to be using.